# What's the easiest way to have a border around an image with one pixel inside (and above) the image?

Tags: css

I have a square image that looks round with a `border-radius` of 50%. I want to apply a 10px thick border around this image but instead of having the border "starting" at the edge of the image, I want it to "start" 1 pixel inside the edge of the image, meaning that the 1px upper contour of the image will be hidden underneath the border.

What is the simplest way to achieve this effect? I tried with `box-shadow` without much success.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle of the code you have at the moment?

Comment: Please post some code, but don't post a jsfiddle when you can include your code on SO. It's not advised to put your code on a 3rd party site when you can just as easily include it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the image *into* a DIV to which you apply the desired size, border and border-radius.

Then apply `height: calc(100% + 1px); width: auto;` (or the other way round) and `margin-top: -1px; margin-left: -1px` to the image itself. (You might make that one or two pixels more each - just try what looks better)

And make sure to apply `overflow: hidden` to the parent element to really cut off that additional pixel..

Answer (score 0):

I think the following CSS will do:

```
#MyImage{
  display:block;
  border:10px solid black;
  box-shadow:0px 1px 1px black inset;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhnw5ntv/) with exaggerated dimensions to demonstrate the concept.

Personally, I'd rework the image in Photoshop or equivalent and add the border exactly like you want it in the image editor.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't create an inside border of 1px. It creates part of it, like a half circle.

Comment: Can you post an image of the end-result? I still recommend you manipulate images offline and not with CSS.